# Maclaurin Series of $1-x+\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}\ldots$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I was asked to find the sum of the following series:
\begin{equation}1-\ln 3 + \frac{(\ln 3)^2}{2!} - \frac{(\ln 3)^3}{3!}\ldots\end{equation}

I generalized it to the power series:
\begin{equation} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^n}{n!}\end{equation}
But I don't think I can compute the sum of this series. So then I tried to do this:
\begin{align*}1-\ln x &= 1-(x-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}\ldots)\\
&=1-x+\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}\ldots\end{align*}
Which *seemed* to be in the right shape, so I thought $1-\ln(1+\ln3)$ was my answer, but it obviously wasn't hence the question. Can anyone give me some hints on whether I shold be comparing it to another series, or if I misused The Constant Multiple Law for Series?

Comment: I think you need to double-check your series expansion for the natural log, that factorial doesn't seem right. I would also suggest you check out the series expansion for $e^x.$

Comment: I think it's the series expansion of $$e^{-x}$$ and not of log x.

Comment: Do you know the series if ever minus ($-$) was a plus?

Comment: @StephenDonovan tysm, I'm still struggling with infinite series.

Comment: @SandipanSamanta Yeah, I realized now. A new thing to add to my notes though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here is a hint:** do you know the series for the exponential? For $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n
$$
where $a_n=??$

Then, try to see how you can use this for your problem.

---

As a side note, regarding your attempt: the power series for $\log$ does not have any factorial: $\log (1+x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}{n}$, for $|x|<1$.

Comment: Just as a passing comment, this series isn't only used for real $x$ as stated in the answer, but also for complex numbers and matrices. (in fact I believe this is the definition of the exponential of a matrix)

Comment: @StephenDonovan Good point regarding complex numbers. As for the definition: it sometimes is used as the defintiion, sometimes some other definition (as solution of a differential equation, as a reciprocal, etc.) is used, and the equivalence of defintiions then has to be proven.

Comment: This is the series for $\log(1+x)$.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Thanks! Somehow I missed that obvious typo (oops...). Fixed.

Comment: Thanks, I still get mixed up with all of the factorials that are floating around in my brain.